# Ordenar un array con sort dadas ciertas condiciones

Tags: javascript

estoy programando un sistema de cola de producción...
Sin embargo, no logro entender como debería codificarlo si lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

Supongamos que tenemos 4 registros/entradas de cola...

```
[{"id_entrada":1, "fecha_entrada":"2023-01-02 07:54:00", "fecha_inicio_produccion":"2023-01-02 08:15:00", "minutos_estimados":"64", "fecha_fin_produccion":"2023-01-02 09:19:00", "id_herramental": "71", "estatus":"produciendo"},{"id_entrada":2, "fecha_entrada":"2023-01-02 08:19:30", "fecha_inicio_produccion":"2023-01-02 09:34:00", "minutos_estimados":"45", "fecha_fin_produccion":"2023-01-02 10:19:00", "id_herramental": "115", "estatus":"en cola"}, ,{"id_entrada":3, "fecha_entrada":"2023-01-02 08:23:45", "fecha_inicio_produccion":"2023-01-02 10:34:00", "minutos_estimados":"30", "fecha_fin_produccion":"2023-01-02 11:04:00", "id_herramental": "70", "estatus":"en cola"} ,{"id_entrada":4, "fecha_entrada":"2023-01-02 08:30:10", "fecha_inicio_produccion":"2023-01-02 11:19:00", "minutos_estimados":"60", "fecha_fin_produccion":"2023-01-02 12:19:00", "id_herramental": "71", "estatus":"en cola"}]
```

el orden que deseo ver es:

- que se muestren agrupados con forme los herramentales que coincidan... por ejemplo entrada 1 y 4 usan el mismo herramental, por lo tanto debería sugerir que luego de terminar con la entrada 1, siga con la 4, por que al ser el mismo herramental se puede ahorrar el tiempo de desmontaje/montaje de herramental en esta producción.
- además, siempre debe dar la prioridad como primer registro al que tenga estatus "produciendo" para que se mire al principio de toda la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la siguiente funcion de sort para este caso:

```js
function customSort(a, b) {
    if (a.id_herramental === b.id_herramental) {
        return a.id === 'produciendo' 
            ? -1
            : 1
    }
    
    return +a.id_herramental - +b.id_herramental;
}
```

En el primer condicional revisamos el punto

> además, siempre debe dar la prioridad como primer registro al que tenga estatus "produciendo" para que se mire al principio de toda la tabla.

Acá si dos `id_herramental` son iguales, procedemos a dar la prioridad al registro que tenga el valor 'produciendo'

Para el siguiente punto:

> que se muestren agrupados con forme los herramentales que coincidan... por ejemplo entrada 1 y 4 usan el mismo herramental, por lo tanto debería sugerir que luego de terminar con la entrada 1, siga con la 4, por que al ser el mismo herramental se puede ahorrar el tiempo de desmontaje/montaje de herramental en esta producción.

Basta con hacer una comparación numérica directa haciendo un casteo de string a number del `id_herramental`

Asi queda finalmente:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id_entrada": 1,
        "fecha_entrada": "2023-01-02 07:54:00",
        "fecha_inicio_produccion": "2023-01-02 08:15:00",
        "minutos_estimados": "64",
        "fecha_fin_produccion": "2023-01-02 09:19:00",
        "id_herramental": "71",
        "estatus": "produciendo"
    },
    {
        "id_entrada": 2,
        "fecha_entrada": "2023-01-02 08:19:30",
        "fecha_inicio_produccion": "2023-01-02 09:34:00",
        "minutos_estimados": "45",
        "fecha_fin_produccion": "2023-01-02 10:19:00",
        "id_herramental": "115",
        "estatus": "en cola"
    },
    {
        "id_entrada": 3,
        "fecha_entrada": "2023-01-02 08:23:45",
        "fecha_inicio_produccion": "2023-01-02 10:34:00",
        "minutos_estimados": "30",
        "fecha_fin_produccion": "2023-01-02 11:04:00",
        "id_herramental": "70",
        "estatus": "en cola"
    },
    {
        "id_entrada": 4,
        "fecha_entrada": "2023-01-02 08:30:10",
        "fecha_inicio_produccion": "2023-01-02 11:19:00",
        "minutos_estimados": "60",
        "fecha_fin_produccion": "2023-01-02 12:19:00",
        "id_herramental": "71",
        "estatus": "en cola"
    }
];

function customSort(a, b) {
    if (a.id_herramental === b.id_herramental) {
        return a.id === 'produciendo' 
            ? -1
            : 1
    }
    
    return +a.id_herramental - +b.id_herramental;
}

data.sort(customSort);

console.log({data})
```